# Permissions issue in SQL Server 2016 and R

Tags: sql-server, r, permissions, sql-server-2016

We’re very experienced with SQL Server as well as R (as a standalone product). We’ve setup SQL Server 2016 test server (production version from MSDN) with R also installed. The machine works fine, and we’ve tried some rudimentary R, and that works fine as well (which also means that we’ve referred to this article from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx).

So, the issue we’re having is trying to load an R script from a location on our network. For example:

```
source(“\\\\MyServer\\MyRDirectory\\MyRScript.R”);
```

Just in case UNC didn’t work, we tried mapping a network drive to a drive letter, but received the same, “No such file or directory” error message.

There seems to be a permissions issue accessing this file. If we copy that file to the local test server, it works fine. For example, we have no issue with this:

```
source(“C:\\Temp\\MyRScript.R”);
```

For this test, I am using SSMS 2016 and I am logged in as a Windows AD user with DBO permissions, and I have permissions to the remote folder. The SQL Server 2016 service accounts are also AD “users” with appropriate permissions. I read that R has its own user group (SQLRUserGroup) and 20 user accounts are in that group – all of this is assigned by SQL Server during the install; these are accounts that are local to the test machine. I suspect this is the issue: R/SQL Server must be trying to access that network folder/file as a local user – not an AD user with appropriate permissions.

Has anyone run into this and found a resolution that you can share?

FYI, as expected, running the following R script in SQL Server 2016 (SSMS):

```
execute sp_execute_external_script
@language = N’R’
, @script = N’ OutputDataSet<- data.frame(c(USERNAME=Sys.getenv("USERNAME")),HOME=Sys.getenv("HOME"))'
, @input_data_1 = N''
WITH RESULT SETS ((USERNAME varchar(200),HOME varchar(200)))
```

Reports that my script is running as "MSSQLSERVER01" with a local/home directory and GUID for that user. I'm sure that's the issue, but how do I change that to run as an AD user with proper permissions?

I get the strong feeling that this is not going to be possible, but can anyone here verify?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server R Services always runs the scripts in the context of worker accounts that are local to the system, for security and isolation purposes. And it is not possible to run them in the AD user context.

Comment: That's what I suspected after reading through all the articles from Microsoft. Bummer. I wonder if that's why we're having trouble using a Trusted Connection to one of our database servers within the script: `conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=MySQLServer;database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True")`

Comment: Trusted connection from R script back to the database running SQL Server R services is a supported scenario. Can you confirm if you have gone through the setup step for [Enable Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx)? What is the error message you are getting?